# How convert http status code into number?

Tags: c#

I read the `status` code of http like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
string text;

HttpStatusCode status;

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   text = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
   status = response.StatusCode;
}
```

now if the API return `204` instead of the number (204) I get:

> No content

I tried to covert into: `status = (int) response.StatusCode;` but the compiler tell me:

> Redundant cast

What I did wrong?

Comment: It's already an int why do you want to cast it again?

Comment: `HttpStatusCode` is an enum based on `int`, and you can assign it to an `int` without casting.

Comment: @billybob cause instead of the number (204) I get `No Content`

Comment: right its an ENUM so it will cast to int by default. but not the right int.

Comment: @j_mcnally the HttpStatusCode is perfectly mapped to the right int value, a NoContent has an int value of 204.

Comment: @Gusman that is correct my fault.

Comment: yeah so the status code should already be the proper int.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you did not declare `status` as an integer:

```
HttpStatusCode status;
```

So you're trying to cast `status` to the same type that it was declared as, which is redundant.  Change the above line to:

```
int status;
```

And try again.